# Roll Up Summary using Aggregate result map

Tags: soql, aggregateresult

I using the below trigger code for rollup summary. I want to use aggregate result in a map to fullfil rollup summary. How to do it.

```
Deal__c M = [select name, Number_of_Activities__c, oppactvitycount__c  from Deal__c where id =:newOpportunity.Deal__c];
List<AggregateResult > groupedResults = [select sum(No_of_Activities__c)aver from Opportunity  where Deal__c =: M.id]; 
Decimal decimalRevenue = 0;
if(groupedResults.size() > 0)
{  

String str = '' + groupedResults[0].get('aver') ; 
    if(str!='null'){
decimalRevenue = Decimal.ValueOf(str) ; 
    }
System.debug('decimalRevenue ::::: ' + decimalRevenue) ;  
} 
M.oppactvitycount__c = decimalRevenue;
opportunityactivitycount.add(M);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map this way

```
map<Id, Decimal> mapDealIdToNoOfActivity = new map<Id, Decimal>();
for(AggregateResult agrRst: [select sum(No_of_Activities__c)aver, Deal__c 
                               from Opportunity  
                              where Deal__c =: M.id GROUP BY Deal__c])
{
    mapDealIdToNoOfActivity.put((Id) agrRst.get('Deal__c'), (decimal) agrRst.get('aver') );
}
```

after use this map to get sum value based on deal Id and assign to  opp field

### Updates

```
List<Deal__c> lstDeal = new List<Deal__c>();
```

Iterate over map

```
for(Id dealId: mapDealIdToNoOfActivity.keyset())
{
  lstDeal.add(new Deal__c(Id = dealId, 
                          DealField__c = mapDealIdToNoOfActivity.get(dealId)));
}

update lstDeal;
```

or if you want to skip map variable then use

```
List<Deal__c> lstDeal = new List<Deal__c>();

for(AggregateResult agrRst: [select sum(No_of_Activities__c)aver, Deal__c 
                               from Opportunity  
                              where Deal__c =: M.id GROUP BY Deal__c])
{
    lstDeal.add(new Deal__c(Id = (Id) agrRst.get('Deal__c'), 
                            DealField__c = (decimal) agrRst.get('aver')));
}

update lstDeal;
```

Comment: Hi sfdcweb.. I need to update the sum(No_of_Activities__c) in Deal__c object .. How to get the sum value and assign to  Deal__c object field..

Comment: @Sid check my updates..